# rgl.snapshot produces a black file

Tags: r, plot, rgl

Example:

```
example(plot3d)
rgl.snapshot('test.png') # snapshot3d('test.png')
```

I become a black png file since today.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgl_0.93.996

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.2
```

rgl.postscript needs 200s for saving of my files, this is too long.
What can I do?

Comment: What changed since it last worked? Reinstall the `rgl` package. If all else fails and you only need a few screengrabs, use an operating-system screenshot capture program.

Comment: I have nothing changed. It´s a client PC and i have no permission to change anything. On other PC's works it.

Comment: Run: capabilities()  on the target machine.   My guess is the the png device is not present. You may want to use Cairo-png

Comment: capabilities() say PNG is TRUE. CairoPNG produces a black file by 3D plots too. 2D works.